# How to resume your app using calaba.sh

Tags: ios, cucumber, xcode5, calabash

I'm using Calaba.sh to to ui testing of my iOS app. I want to be able to test tapping on a link in the app which takes the user to a web address in their browser. I then want to be able  to resume the app. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in Calabash iOS.